# Ubuntu 12.04 not detecting windows 7 os during installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I just bought a Lenovo y500 and freshly installed Windows 7-32 bit, which is working fine. Now I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 with dual boot. But it's not detecting Windows 7 and shows the whole disk as empty.

[Boot info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5615279/)

Please help me.

Solution:
Followed the steps mentioned in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193144/dual-boot-uefi-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-both-64-bits-w7-entry-doesnt-appea)

Comment: Did you try installing Ubuntu using wubi installer? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. its written there that wubi doesn't work with pc using UEFI firmware. And my laptop is using UEFI firmware

Comment: yeah right, my bad. Try and Partition the disk in Windows and then install Ubuntu on the new Partition.

Comment: Here's a Link i found... [Win7 UEFI Dual boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193144/dual-boot-uefi-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-both-64-bits-w7-entry-doesnt-appea)

Comment: And another... This looks promising :) [LINK](http://en.community.dell.com/owners-club/alienware/f/3746/p/19461328/20161438.aspx)

Comment: Someone has similar problem, but there's an answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/287352/ubuntu-13-04-amd64-installation-does-not-detect-windows-7

Comment: thanks MrSeed I followed the steps written in the first link u mentioned and it worked like a charm. Thanks guys for suggesting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it says stuff like:

```
=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not EFI-compatible.
EFI in dmesg.
```

Maybe it was booted in legacy mode and not in EFI mode?
It also says:

```
Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
```

Maybe something is broken? Or it's only a side effect of not booting in EFI mode?

Please someone, convert this answer into a comment :)