# Showing error unknown filesystem after i deleted the linux partition fron windows

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-gnome

I installed Ubuntu Gnome from unallocated space. And later I deleted the unallocated space and made a disk partition in windows. After that i cant log into my laptop Lenovo G50-45

Answer (score 0):

re: 'installed ubuntu-gnome from [into?] unallocated space'
where the unallocated became allocated space & a partition I assume.

re: 'later I deleted the unallocated space and made disk partition'
if it was still unallocated - I don't understand your problem; if however you created an allocated partition to install ubuntu, then wiped it, the fact that you installed ubuntu re-wrote your MBR (master boot record) that pointed to a portion of the disk where the grub menu appeared that let you run ubuntu or windoze. this likely is now pointing to a non-mbr record in your new 'disk partition in windows' which can't perform chain-loading to your windows. thus you need MBR fixed.

I don't know your g50-45 (eufi or legacy); and have no idea of what version of windoze you have, so I'll suggest

[How to restore Windows 7 MBR without a CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5748/how-to-restore-windows-7-mbr-without-a-cd)

[Restoring the MBR](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381447/restoring-the-mbr)

Comment: So how do i install Ubuntu using bootable pendrive

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu